# (react-chartjs-2 | NextJS | typescript | bar chart ) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-chartjs-2

I am running into an error where the console is throwing an error  of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`  I am new to NextJS & Typescript and I am  trying to create a simple bar chart.

Error message:

```
react-dom.development.js?03cb:22839 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at setDatasets (index.js?ad43:24:1)
    at cloneData (index.js?ad43:45:1)
    at renderChart (index.js?ad43:87:1)
    at eval (index.js?ad43:149:1)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js?03cb:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js?03cb:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js?03cb:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js?03cb:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js?03cb:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js?03cb:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js?03cb:26984:1)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js?03cb:26769:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js?b1d2:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js?b1d2:239:1)
```

`components/BarChart.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ChartData,
  } from 'chart.js';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export interface DataSet {
  label: string,
  data: number[],
  borderColor: string,
  backgroundColor: string
}

export interface BarChartProps {
  options: any,
  data: ChartData<'bar'>
}

export function BarChart(options: any, data: ChartData<'bar'>) {
  return <Bar options={options} data={data} />;
}
```

`src/pages/dashboard/index.tsx`

```
import {FC} from 'react';
import {BarChart, BarChartProps} from '../../../components/BarChart'
import indexData from '../../../data/index.json'
import {DataSet} from '../../../components/BarChart'
import {ChartData, ChartOptions} from 'chart.js'
import React from 'react';

interface IndexData {
    [key: string]: number | string;
    table_name: string
    index_name: string
    index_scans_count: number
    index_scan_tuple_read: number
    index_scan_tuple_fetch: number
    index_size: number,
    table_reads_index_count: number,
    table_reads_seq_count: number,
    table_reads_count: number,
    table_writes_count: number,
    table_size: number
  }

const rawData: IndexData[] = indexData;
const indexNames: string[] = Object.keys(indexData[0]).filter((k: string) => typeof rawData[0][k] === 'number');

const generateData = (data: IndexData[]): DataSet[] =>{
    const res: DataSet[] = [];
    indexNames.forEach((name: string) => {
        res.push({
            label: name,
            data: data.map((row: IndexData)=> row[name] as number),
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        });
    });

    return res;
};


export async function getStaticProps(){
    const options: ChartOptions<'bar'> = {
        indexAxis: 'y' as const,
        elements: {
                bar: {
                borderWidth: 2,
            },
        },
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'right' as const,
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Index Performance Charts',
            },
        },
    };

    const chartData: ChartData= {
        labels: indexNames,
        datasets: generateData(rawData),
    };

    return {
        props:{
            options: options,
            data: chartData
        }
    }
}


const Charts: FC<BarChartProps> = (props) =>{
    return <BarChart options={props.options} data={props.data}/>
}

export default Charts;
```

Log of my `chartData`

```
{
  labels: [
    'index_scans_count',
    'index_scan_tuple_read',
    'index_scan_tuple_fetch',
    'index_size',
    'table_reads_index_count',
    'table_reads_seq_count',
    'table_reads_count',
    'table_writes_count',
    'table_size'
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'index_scans_count',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      label: 'index_scan_tuple_read',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      label: 'index_scan_tuple_fetch',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      label: 'index_size',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      label: 'table_reads_index_count',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      label: 'table_reads_seq_count',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      label: 'table_reads_count',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      label: 'table_writes_count',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    },
    {
      label: 'table_size',
      data: [Array],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
    }
  ]
} chartData
```

When I put the same code inside `components` it works. But when I shifted it out into `dashboard` folder somehow it doesn't. Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, the solution was to define the interface of the props in BarChart to be as such:

`components/BarChart.tsx`

```
export interface BarChartProps {
  options: any,
  data: ChartData<'bar'>
}

export function BarChart({options, data}: BarChartProps) {
  console.log(data, 'data-any')
  return <Bar options={options} data={data} />;
}
```

instead of

```
export function BarChart(options: any, data: ChartData<'bar'>) {
  console.log(data, 'data-any')
  return <Bar options={options} data={data} />;
}
```

This is when I am doing this in `pages/dashboard/index.tsx`

```
const Charts: FC<BarChartProps> = (props) =>{
    return <BarChart options={props.options} data={props.data}/>
}
```

Apparently in typescript, the props must be defined together if they are used together. If not typescript cannot infer their types properly.